# Retrieving a hidden column image in datagridview error

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am new in C# Windows Forms and MS SQL Server. So any help is much appreciated. I am trying to retrieve a hidden image in my datagridview however when I run the code and select a specific cell in the datagridview and display all the data including the image, I got an error that says,
'Unable to cast object of type 'system.string' to type 'system.byte '.

Here is my code,

```
if (dataGVInventory.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
            {
                Byte[] dataImg = new byte[0];
                dataImg = (Byte[])dataGVInventory.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(dataImg);
                pbInvImg.Image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
                txtProdName.Text = dataGVInventory.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtProdDesc.Text = dataGVInventory.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                txtQuantity.Text = dataGVInventory.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                cmbAddCategory.Text = dataGVInventory.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();

                //Set enable fields of textbox and button to true.
                btnInvChooseImg.Enabled = true;
                txtProdName.Enabled = true;
                txtProdDesc.Enabled = true;
                txtQuantity.Enabled = true;
                cmbAddCategory.Enabled = true;
                btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
                btnDelete.Enabled = true;
            }
```

This is how I load the data to the datagridview.

```
private void frmInventory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        loadInventory();

    }

    private void loadInventory()
    {
        dataGVInventory.Rows.Clear();
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT PRODUCTS.PID, PRODUCTS.ProductImage, PRODUCTS.ProductName, PRODUCTS.ProductDescription, PRODUCTS.Quantity, CATEGORY.CategoryName FROM PRODUCTS INNER JOIN 
                               CATEGORY ON PRODUCTS.CID = CATEGORY.CID;", con);

        try
        {
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                dataReader();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    public void dataReader()
    {
        dataGVInventory.Rows.Add(rdr[0].ToString(),
                            rdr[1].ToString(),
                            rdr[2].ToString(),
                            rdr[3].ToString(),
                            rdr[4].ToString(),
                            rdr[5].ToString());
    }
```

The datatype of the image in the SQL is varbinary(MAX). Any idea what did I miss?

Comment: why `rdr[1].ToString()` in `dataGVInventory.Rows.Add`? remove the `ToString()`

Comment: OMG, I didn't notice that after hours of searching for solution. I guess I need some sleep. Haha. Anyways, thank you so much sir @AJITH.

Comment: There is no need to manually transfer data at all - use something like a datatable as the datasource